# How to use list of object ids inside $in inside $match in mongodb aggregation for redash visualization

Tags: json, mongodb, redash

I am trying to create a visualization in redash using mongo query, for few ids.I am trying to add multiple ids inside match , but its giving error, how we can give a list of object ids to match

```
{
"collection": "abc", 
"aggregate": [
    {
        "$match": {
            "_id": {
                "$in": [
                    "$oid":"65372536"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind": {
            "path": "$rest",
            "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "name": "$rest.name",
            "age": "$rest.age"
        }
    }]}
```

how can I give multiple object ids inside match

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: @user20042973 Error running query: Invalid query format. The query is not a valid JSON. this is the error I am getting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

solved this question by adding {} for object ids

```
   {
    "collection": "abc", 
   "aggregate": [
{
    "$match": {
        "_id": {
            "$in": [
                {"$oid":"65372536"},
                {"$oid":"67468299"},
                {"$oid":"69087654"}
            ]
        }
    }
},
{
    "$unwind": {
        "path": "$rest", 
        "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
    }
},
{
    "$project": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "name": "$rest.name",
        "age": "$rest.age"
    }
}]}
```